# What are useful architectures for storing user settings?

Tags: php, database-design, laravel-5

I want to store some user settings and I thought of 3 options, since it's my first project and I want to start it the right way, I can't figure out which is the the optimal way of doing this..

1. Storing single settings directly in columns in the user table
2. Having a user_settings table with the columns setting_name, setting_value and user_id
3. Storing a JSON string in the user table, in a column named something like "user_settings_json"

On a design analysis, I noticed wordpress stores it in a separate table, but I'm not sure that's necessary for every application (since mine does not have nearly as many user settings as wp does)

I'm using Laravel, PHP, javascript/jquery.

Which do you guys think would be, most useful, overall better, in terms of design, serviceability and performance?

Comment: Of course option 1! Think about the benefits of ACID and normalization

Comment: This is a mixture of "personal preference" and "searchability". Do you want to find users with a particular setting (say, email "opt out" or "opt in")? That pretty much removes option 3. Do you have a lot of settings that may change, or may not be relevant for some users? That chops out number 1. Are you using an ORM that doesn't handle joins or pivot tables easily? That chops out number 2. Personally, number 2 is my preference, but it really depends on the specific situation.

Comment: @bub option 1 is horrible once you have enough settings (or the settings don't apply to all users). I would rather not have a table with 100+ columns which are half empty.

Comment: @samlev then generate 5 tables with 20 columns if you have 100 settings and you dont want to have only 1 table

Comment: @bub - I *really* hope you're being sarcastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing a JSON string ? NO !

You want to be able to isolate the settings, just query what you need. Therefore, keep it in separate columns!

As for the question if you have to make a separate table, no, you don't have to. When you just got some simple settings you can just add the columns to the existing table of users. Be aware of the limitations here. If you do need advanced settings, i would recommend using a separate table. Better do it too early. Not every setting might apply to every user. For example when you've got premium accounts who can have more settings. So, keeping it separate is what I would do.

Btw, I wouldn't let the columns start with 'setting_' if they are already in a separate table containing 'setting' in the name.

Conclusion: **Option 2 :)**

Comment: I will make a note here that *some* settings are appropriate to be promoted to columns depending on number of users (I'm talking a few hundred thousand), and the speed of specific actions.

Comment: Ofcourse settings heavily related to eachother can be joined in a string or somewhat.

Comment: @bub , why would that be? and how significant are we talking about? It might not be the case that you need all the settings at once..

Comment: Surely it depends on the amount of the stored data and imagine the very usual but special cases when you make your query to find out a group of users that have similar settings.

Comment: Ok, let's take that example of comparing settings between users. A concatinated string might have a diffrent order, marking it very hard. You will have to deserialize, which takes time as well.. right?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've made package for my project which uses Laravel 9 and it allows you to add settings to any Laravel model. It can cast values to primitive types like bool, int, but also to custom classes. Eg.:

```php
$user->settings->get('is_gamer');
$user->settings->set('games_count', 10);

// or global site scoped
Settings::get('display_annoucement');

// more advanced usage with definition of custom class
$address = $user->settings->get('address');
$address->country = 'Poland';
$address->zip = '11-222';
$address->city = 'Warsaw';
$user->settings->put('address', $address);

// any model that implements trait
$article->settings->get('show_breadcrumbs');
$post->settings->get('allow_replies');
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/npabisz/laravel-settings