# Laravel: Allow users to Enable/Disable features in the application

Tags: laravel

Apologies if this violates any Stack overflow terms.

I've been searching for examples to allow users to enable/disable features.

For example, the website is sending database, push and email notifications to users. I want to add checkboxes in their profile to enable/disable if they don't want to receive notifications.

The search results I found are mentioning "Laravel feature Flags" which is not what I'm looking for. Any resource I can read to understand the logic/operation behind this subject?

Thank you

Comment: you can make it yourself create a new table in your database with the name of the user's settings in there and add all the features that you want the user to customize. for example, if the user doesn't want email notifications he/she can disable them. and for your side before sending the notification check in the database for that user

Comment: Search Stackoverflow for *Laravel create user settings*. How about this: [What are useful architectures for storing user settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697068/what-are-useful-architectures-for-storing-user-settings) (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75153757/10441671) promoting a user settings package if you like that. Coding something like this yourself works, too).